# differential equations, chain rule? maybe?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My friend asked me for help in this question, with this info, but i don't really know where to even start....

 They say; $$h(x)= f(g(x)) $$ $h''$ exists for all R, and is continuous. $$g(x) = |2sin(x + 2|x|) + 1|$$ find $f'(3)$

 $h' = f'g'$... but i can't think of anything else. is this enough info to solve this??? possibly if you say $g(x) = 3$ then solve for x, but i don't see where that would lead us. $$f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 +bx^2+cx+d$$

Comment: What does the last line (saying that $f(x)$ equals a polynomial of degree four) has to do with the question? Is it given? Or is it something you want to assume or are trying to prove? You need to arrange your description of the question more logically, so that your readers can understand your question.

Comment: its just what they told me.... i think the equation for f(x) is just given. I don't have the question (since its not in english) so i was trying to solve it from what they told me. I apologise if its not very helpful...